# php if preg_match 4 numbers then a dot and then 2 numbers

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to write an if statement in php with preg_match to say allow 4 numbers and then a dot and then 2 numbers...

This is what I have....

```
$string = "10000.000";

if (preg_match('[/^\d{0,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$/]', $string)){
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

is my preg_match code wrong?

Comment: Your regex allows **up to** four numbers, between `0` and `4`, and the capturing group is optional. So, this will match basically anything.

Comment: :(...how would I rewrite it to do what I want it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as you want it!

```
^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}$
```

`^` start of string,
`[0-9]` a number from 0 to 9,
`{4}` 4x times,
`\.` a dot,
`$` end of the string

Comment: I got an error `Message: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found`

Comment: add / at start and end... like this: /^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}$/